# Adding or subtracting a year (or months) from a prompt

Tags: sql, cognos

Apologies if this has been discussed before (or is ridiculously easy). I'm working within Cognos in native sql.

I'm trying to find a way to find data for the same time last year as the month selected by the user in a prompt. I'd like to retrieve the same data for twelve months prior to a YoY growth variable.

Current code:

```
with
monthsago as 
(select trunc(add_months(sysdate, -#prompt('p_month')#),'mon') as y , last_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -#prompt('p_month')#),'mon'))  as z from dual)
```

The prompt format is YYYY-MM

Comment: This kind of relative time calculation is very easy using OLAP sources or DMR modelling - have you tried those rather than customizing the Cognos SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something along the lines of

```
DECLARE @Prompt date = '2014-10-01';
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(@Prompt AS DATE));
```

This assumes using the first date of the given month.